# The importance of initializing a variable?

Tags: php, variables, initialization

I'm trying to understand the importance of initializing a variable, before assigning a value to it in those rare cases where for example, you might be creating an array within a loop.

**For example;**

```
foreach($var1 as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = $key;
}
```

In this example, `$array` hasn't been declared before it's used to contain an array, which I've been told is bad practice, but I have no idea why. I've been advised to instead do this;

```
$array = array();

foreach($var1 as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = $key;
}
```

**Another example, when constructing a long string based on many array values:**

```
$size = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $string .= $array[$i]."del".$array_2[$i].",";
}
```

I've been told it should be done like this

```
$string = null;

$size = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $string .= $array[$i]."del".$array_2[$i].",";
}
```

***I'm wondering why, in both these cases, it's advised to initialize the variable before assigning data to it? Or this not the case, and I've simply heard wrong. Are there exceptions to this rule, if it does exist?***

**Update:** Would this be the proper way to initialize variables in this function?

```
function weight_index($keyword, $src, $alt, $content, $ratio='3:3:1') {
    // Initialize needed variables
    $content_index = ''; $src_index = ''; $alt_index = '';

    // Create all four types of $keyword variations: -, _, %20, in order to search 
    // through $content, $alt, $src for instances.
    $keyword_fmt = array('hyphen' => str_replace(' ', '-', $keyword), 'underscore' => str_replace(' ', '_', $keyword), 'encode' => urlencode($keyword), 'original' => $keyword);

    // Define weight index for each instance within a searchable "haystack".
    list($src_weight, $alt_weight, $content_weight) = explode(':', $ratio);

    // Get the number of instances of $keyword in each haystack for all variations.
    foreach($keyword_fmt as $key => $value) {
        $content_index += substr_count($value, $content); // .. may generate an error as $x_index hasn't been initialized.
        $src_index += substr_count($value, $src);
        $alt_index += substr_count($value, $alt);
    }

    // Multiply each instance by the correct ratio.
    $content_index = $content_index * $content_weight;
    $src_index = $src_index * $src_weight;
    $alt_index = $alt_index * $alt_weight;

    // Total up all instances, giving a final $weight_index.
    $weight_index = $content_index + $src_index + $alt_index;

    return $weight_index; 
}
```

Or would it be more prudent to use the `global` keyword in front of variables like `$content_index`, `$src_index` and `$alt_index`, and initialize them in a separate file that would be included i.e. `init_variables.php` that would contain all variables that would need to be initialized before use, as in the examples in this post?

Comment: Variables only used in a function should *not* be `global`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll initialize them inside the function then as in the example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if what you're looping over happens to be an empty array? Then you wind up with `$array` or `$string` never being defined, so when something tries to reference it, your program does bad things.

```
$var1 = array();
foreach($var1 as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = $key;
}
foreach($array as $v) { // errors because $array isn't defined
...
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. Props for the example :)!

Answer (score 2):

For one, not initialising an array will issue a warning. Your code should not do that.

Also, what would happen if you accidentally had an existing array with the same name in scope? This could lead to hard to track bugs.

In your second example, I'd initialise the string as an empty string (`''`), not `null`.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be able to take a look at the quick update I made, concerning the proper method of initialization when a variable is contained within a function?

Comment: Don't use `global` unless you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

Those code blocks will throw warnings.

```
$string .= "asdf";
```

Is just shorthand for

```
$string = $string . $asdf
```

Since it is undefined on the right-hand, this will give the notice `Undefined variable: string`. You'll get a similar notice for trying to add elements to an undefined array varaible.

Initializing variables to default values also makes the code easier to read (most of what programmers do is actually read code, not write code). When you see the assignment `$string = ''` you are cued to keep it in mind. It makes following the code much easier when you don't pull variables out of thin air.

Finally, it's good to note that php is one of the few widely-used languages where you can do something like this at all (it just throws warnings, not errors). Most languages this will just result an error and not run at all.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the clean and thorough explanation!

Comment: Re *"Those code blocks will throw warnings."*: Doesn't that depend on configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

Because using uninitialized variables is considered as something strange in PHP, and it will generate notice and warning level errors, to try and get your attention on this things.

Of course you can turn off reporting errors of this level or reporting all errors. But with notices and warnings turned off you can miss when something really strange will start happening, right?